# Ruby mysql2 extensions built against wrong files location

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I have a directory /tmp/buld_source, where I built MySQL 5.5 using cmake with the correct install prefix

Then I manually copied libmysql to the correct (I hope) location under the prefix specified. Proper include files were copied as well.
After that I built mysql2 gem, providing the path to mysql_config

For some reason the gem is referencing /tmp/buld_source/libmysql/libmysqlclient.16.dylib other than $PREFIX/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib

Of course, while the /tmp/buld_source, gem works. WHen I delete the folder, gem starts complaining there's no the library referenced form the mysql.bundle file.

More details here: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/143/

Am I missing something when building the gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody knows what's the source of the problem?

At least now I know how to fix it: http://yjsoon.com/2011/04/linking-mysql-gem-to-mamp